# Ruby on Rails - Leaflet-rails 'ReferenceError: L is not defined'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, leaflet, rubygems

I am new to Ruby on Rails and Leaflet, but I am trying to implement a map using the gem 'leaflet-rails' version 1.6 with Rails version 6.0.3.2.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27322432/ruby-on-rails-leaflet-rails-not-loading/62891530#62891530) is a similar thread on a similar issue.

I am receiving 'ReferenceError: L is not defined' when I load up my page.. I have followed the install guide and have been trying to implement the map for the last 2 night now, with no avail. The only way I am able to get the map to work is if I add the code below into the HTML file I am trying to implement the map into.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"/>
```

I have checked and I am Using leaflet-rails 1.6.0

I have added 'gem 'leaflet-rails'' to the Gemfile

I have added '*= require leaflet' to the application.css file

I have added '//= require' leaflet to the application.js file

I have added the code below to application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': true %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
```

I have added the code below to the leaflet.rb file I created

```
 ' Leaflet.tile_layer = 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/YOUR-CLOUDMADE-API-KEY/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
# You can also use any other tile layer here if you don't want to use Cloudmade - see http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer for more
Leaflet.attribution = 'Your attribution statement'
Leaflet.max_zoom = 18'
```

When I refresh the page and inspect the HTML, the script is running the below code.

```
var map = L.map('map', {});
map.setView([51.52238797921441, -0.08366235665359283], 18);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/YOUR-CLOUDMADE-API-KEY/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          attribution: 'Your attribution statement',
          maxZoom: 18,
}).addTo(map);
```

If I look inside the head of the file, it seems to be referencing the application.js file, but no where can I see it referencing anything related to Leaflet.

```
<script src="/packs/js/application-9fe6f817df469889a178.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

I am pretty lost on what to try next as I am very new to Rails.

I would highly appreciate any help. Regards, Rory.

Comment: Skip the gem and just install Leaflet through Yarn. You can add the dependency with `yarn add leaflet`. Front-end packages distributed as gems are an obsolete concept in Rails 6. And where generally problematic as they always lagged behind the package the wrapped.

Comment: The `//= require leaflet` comment is a Sprockets directive for the old assets pipeline and won't do anything in Webpack. In Webpack you use its `require('leaflet')` function in your main manifest (or imports). Its a very different beast and you're following outdated instructions. https://github.com/rails/webpacker

Comment: Hi Max, thanks heaps for replying with that information, I really appreciate it. It has been driving me crazy, I've been following everything to the letter and it hasn't been helping, but what you said makes sense now why it doesn't work! I've just installed it through yarn, so I will give it a shot of getting the map to display and I'll report back. Once again, thanks. Rory.

Comment: Just a quick update, took me all of 7 minutes to implement it after I installed it with yarn.. Really helpful to get pointed in the right direction instead of using outdated technologies. Thanks again

Comment: Happy that it worked out for you. You can choose to answer your question yourself to help others that encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Blockquote Skip the gem and just install Leaflet through Yarn. You can add the dependency with yarn add leaflet. Front-end packages distributed as gems are an obsolete concept in Rails 6. And where generally problematic as they always lagged behind the package the wrapped. – max

I was following outdated install instructions on the leaflet-rails github page. I installed leaflet via a gem, which is now obsolete in rails 6 so all my attempts to initialize the map were unsuccessful.

> The //= require leaflet comment is a Sprockets directive for the old assets pipeline and won't do anything in Webpack. In Webpack you use its require('leaflet') function in your main manifest (or imports). Its a very different beast and you're following outdated instructions. github.com/rails/webpacker – max

I then installed leaflet via yarn and initialized it in application.js with `require(leaflet)` and added the leaflet css to it's own file and referenced that in the html.erb file I am working in. Then it was just simply using the inbuilt map helper function and the basic map is working.

```
 <%= map(:center => {
  :latlng => [51.52238797921441, -0.08366235665359283],
  :zoom => 18
}) %>
```

Thanks to Max for solving this issue for me.